# How does JQuery work with files

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can JQuery/JavaScript read/get the file content on the client side, where the file is an image or a text, and store it in a variable?

**EDIT:** can the file putted in the  be handled on the client??

Comment: Please clarify, if you mean something other than is generally being supposed below. For instance, if you're asking whether you can handle files put in an <input type="file" /> or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **security concern**, JS isn't able to read/write any client machine files. 
Try **Java Applet** if you are from Java realm, **Silverlight** from .NET.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible, for obvious reasons once you think about the possible uses:

```
$(function() { //This doesn't work, just an example
  $.getFile("C:\YourPasswords.txt");
});
```

I'm sure that wouldn't be abused at all :)

Answer (score 2):

No, javascript or any javascript library is not able to read contents from disk clientside.

You would have to use an external plugin wich allows for that such as Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Universal Access XP with Firefox or ActiveX with IE.

You can check out example code for this from 
http://code.google.com/p/memonaut/source/browse/trunk/app/saver.js

The example code is for save; similar stuff should be possible for read.
Hope this helps.